# If $\phi$ is a orientation preserving linear automorphism, do we really need to choose the same orientation for the domain and the codomain?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, determinant, orientation

In the [book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIKFc.png) of *Linear Algebra* by Werner Greub, at pages $131-132$, it is given that

[image]
and

[image]

However, when $\phi$ is a linear automorphism, it says that $\Delta_F = \Delta_E$, and derives the following result, however, as far as I see, there is no obligation for such thing, so is this really just an assumption of the author, or do we really need to set $\Delta_F$ as $\Delta_E$ ? Note that the author is saying that "Then we have $\Delta_F = \Delta_F$", which totally confuses me.

I mean I tried with the case where $\Delta_F$ and $\Delta_E$ represents different orientations for $E$, and the result also changed with this choice, so is there anything I'm missing ? and is my results are correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In discussing orientation of linear transformations, one (naturally and customarily) *fixes an orientation* for each vector space under consideration. Consequently, if $E = F$, then $\Delta_{E} = \Delta_{F}$.

Comment: After reading your answer, I have realised, actually the author have used this logic in many places of the book, for example when if defines a linear automorphism and constructing the matrix representation of it etc. Thanks for pointing out.